# Mysql: How do I insert an array of objects into a column?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

[image]I am trying to insert an array into MYSQL and am having trouble with it. The idea is to add something like:

```
[{"id": "433"}, {"id": "424"}]
```

I have the code below but it seems to be giving me issues, my array does not show in the relevant column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_table (
   id SERIAL,
   foo_ids JSON, 
   name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO foo_table (id, foo_ids, name) VALUES (
   1,
   JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
      `foo_ids`,
      '$',
      CAST('{"id": "432"}' AS JSON),
      '$',
      CAST('{"id": "433"}' AS JSON)
   ),
   'jumbo burger'
);

SELECT * FROM foo_table;
```

Comment: In general, you should [normalize](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-database-normalization-in-sql-server/) your data, so you don't have to insert an "array" into a column.   But as long as you're using [JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()](https://database.guide/json_array_append-append-values-to-a-json-array-in-mysql/) - would you clarify exactly what "issues" you're having?

Comment: this is just an example, I added the issue, it isn't showing up

Comment: @Barmar [SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()` has to be a JSON array. `INSERT` can't refer to a column unless you use `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT column... FROM tablename`.

You can provide an empty array as the first argument.

```
INSERT INTO foo_table (id, foo_ids, name) VALUES (
   1,
   JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
      '[]',
      '$',
      CAST('{"id": "432"}' AS JSON),
      '$',
      CAST('{"id": "433"}' AS JSON)
   ),
   'jumbo burger'
);
```

If you actually want to append to an existing array in the table, you should be using `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`.

Comment: I question the wisdom of advocating such a solution in this instance

Comment: @Strawberry I've long questioned the value of JSON in MySQL, but it seems like we're stuck with it and people are using it.